# Vue.js / Algolia - Dynamically pass field names in template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, algolia, instantsearch.js

I am trying to dynamically show search results from Algolia, based on an array of names.

`Input.vue`:

```
<search-results title="Books" :fields="['booking_reference','shipment_reference']"></search-results>
```

`Results.vue`:

```
<template slot-scope="{ result }">
     <h1 v-for="field in fields">{{ result.field }}</h1>
</template>
```

However, above code does not return anything in my template. It's just blank.

But my `fields` array does indeed have values:

[image]

And I can see the results from Algolia as well:

[image]

But it does not show the results.

If I edit the code and hardcode the field name I want to show, like this:

```
<template slot-scope="{ result }">
          {{ result.booking_reference }}
</template>
```

I can see the result just fine in my template.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

How can I do this with a multidimensional array?

My array:

```
fields:Array[2]
0:Object
maintitle:"booking_reference"
1:Object
subtitle:"shipment_reference"
```

I need to be able to access it like:

`result.maintitle.field`

Comment: Your usage of scoped slots in `Results.vue` implies there's another inner component. If that's the case, please update the code to show the inner component's definition. Otherwise, you don't need scoped slots at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 <h1 v-for="field in fields">{{ result[field] }}</h1>
```

instead of

```
 <h1 v-for="field in fields">{{ result.field }}</h1>
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my updated question? I am trying to do the same, but this time with a multidimensional array

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly, but try this `<h1 v-for="(field, fieldKey) in fields">{{ result[fieldKey][field] }}</h1>`